# Issues with Anaconda install - Failed to create Anaconda menus

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, failed-installation

I had Anaconda version 3.5 installed on my machine but I decided to uninstall it (via the control panel) and to download version 2.7 instead. I am using Windows 7.

However, I have an error message towards the end of the installation where I receive a pop up window saying: `Failed to create Anaconda menus` and then another one saying `Failed to add Anaconda to the system PATH`.

When I click ignore on these pop ups the installation is finished but I do not even see Anaconda in my start menu.

I used different installers (4.2.0 and 4.1.1) but it still not working.

I tried to install it for all users (as I read on the Internet) but it still did not work. The error message was different (see link below) followed by the pop up `Failed to create Anaconda menus`.

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/24353213/20858712/e4438f60-b94b-11e6-806b-f01436aac306.PNG

Can you please help as I am stuck and cannot use it at all?

Answer (score 26):

2.5 years later, I had the same problem installing v2019.07, but the version actually doesn't matter.  Anaconda has had this bug in the installer for a long time.

- 2019.07 successfully installed on one of my dev boxes
- 2019.07 failed to create menus on a second dev box with a very similar environment.  Both Anaconda and Miniconda failed.  I tried everything in this thread, and then some.

Finally I went to the [download archive](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) and grabbed 2019.03, which installed with no issues.  This fixed it for me, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I tried all the suggested solutions. Only yours worked for me, thank you =)

Comment: Thanks Paul, this helped me.I was also getting same issue, 2019.03 installed without error.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me installing Anaconda for python 2.7 and 3.7.

Comment: This is reallly a sturbon bug, now in 2022.02, the bug still annoys me

Comment: I solved the problem installing version 2019.07. Tried everything else. Windows 7.

Comment: is there a miniconda alternative solution for this? Trying this in my VM and anaconda is way too bloated for that

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install from Windows Safe Mode. There were no errors during the installation.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Please update your response to include more information.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent T Sorry, see my answer now

Answer (score 3):

I almost spent two days running in circles trying all the solutions I could find on the Internet, but here is what worked for me.

So, `CondaHTTPError` aka `SSL module is not available` error is caused by the missing/misplacement of **libcrypto** file in anaconda3/DLLs folder:

**Tl;dr**:

> From anaconda3\Library\bin copy below files and paste them in anaconda3/DLLs:

```
-   libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
-   libssl-1_1-x64.dll
```

**Detailed answer**:

1. **Uninstall** any **Python** versions you have (e.g. Python 3.7 or Python 3.8)

   > go to Control Panel--> Program and Features--> Select Python-->
   >   uninstall
2. **Uninstall** any **Anaconda** versions you might have (e.g. Anaconda or miniConda)
   For Anaconda:

   > go to **Control Panel**--> **Program and Features**--> Select **Anaconda**-->**uninstall**

   For miniConda

   > go to **Control Panel**--> **Program and Features**--> Select **miniconda**--> **uninstall**
3. **Delete** any **leftover Environment variables**

   > go to **Control Panel**--> **System**--> **Advanced System settings** (on left side)--> in **System Properties** click on **Environment Variables** button--> in **User Variable** select **Path** and click the **Edit** button--> **delete** any path related to Anaconda, miniConda or Python.

   ```
   E.g.
   C:\Users\Bob \AppData\Local\Programs\Anaconda\...
   C:\Users\Bob \AppData\Local\Programs\miniconda\...
   ```

   b.  If you don’t see any paths related to Anaconda, miniConda or Python; you are good to go.
4. **Reboot** your machine
5. **Download** the latest version of [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)
6. **Run** the **Installer**; keep all the default settings
7. **Go to** your **`anaconda3/library/bin` folder**:

   E.g.`C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin`
8. **Copy** these **files**:

   `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`

   `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`
9. **paste** these **in `anaconda3/DLLs` folder**:
10. **Reopen** the **Anaconda Prompt and test** with any command that requires an Internet connection. 
    E.g. 
    `conda update conda` 
    Or with
    `conda update --all`

Comment: fail to create menus means we cannot even find the anaconda prompt...

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue while installing Anaconda 3.5, please follow the steps below before you start installation :

1. Delete old Python versions from your PC/Laptop
2. Clear path variables which have created on your PC
3. Turn off your anti virus program before you start installation
4. If you have JDK installed on your machine, uninstall it, also delete JAVA path created in variable

Answer (score 1):

Could you try choosing run as administrator before clicking Anaconda 3 installation? That fixed mine.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me (Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64)

Answer (score -1):

Tried this as well, using 5.0.0 and 4.4.0 installer, tried as local user, admin user, install as administrator, clicked the "add to path", but none of these worked. Every time I got the same "failed to install menus"

Then I added the Anaconda target directory `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` to the end of my Path, re-ran the installer (5.0.0) and it finally worked.

Comment: Did not work for me (Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64)

Answer (score -1):

This is complete process. With this step you cat install your Anaconda of any version(not need to download miniconda).

If you are window user or any OS you are using first download Anacond.

first you need to delete all language(java,python etc) variable path which is set via environment variable.

If you are window user then need to off window defender.

After that uninstall all antivirus software(If you using antivirus software you will not get menu ).

And install Anacoda you can install perfectly.100% working

Answer (score -1):

1. Turn off the antivirus installed in your computer before installing the anaconda setup.
2. During installation select its access to all users which requires admin permission then the default path automatically changes into C/Program Data/Anaconda 3.
   Then it won't show any errors :)

Comment: Did not work for me (Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64).