# Anaconda 3: Failed to create menus

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, data-science

How to resolve '*failed to create menus*' error while installing **anaconda 3** in windows 7?

I tried to changes in my environment variable but I can't resolve this problem.

I think this is the problem related to path variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with Anaconda install - Failed to create Anaconda menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182477/issues-with-anaconda-install-failed-to-create-anaconda-menus)

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Note this question was already asked: have you tried the suggestions there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182477/issues-with-anaconda-install-failed-to-create-anaconda-menus

Answer (score 0):

hey this problem of failed-to-create-menus is solved for WINDOWS 7. Download the setup from https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/
[See the picture below for the selected item][the red one]

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless